# Possible to maintain a DNS entry without a connected server?

Tags: domain-name-system

We have a client that is attempting to access a server by IP, that has been deactivated for quite a while. I'm trying to figure out what server replaced it, but I'm curious as to why the IP remains routable? There is no server connected, and the related IP's no longer appear in the hosting account management page.

How do I figure out what is maintaining this record?

C:\Users\xxxxxxx >nslookup xx.x.xxx.x

Server:  server.company.com

Address:  10.xxx.x.xx

Name:    [deactivated server name]

Address:  xx.x.xxx.x

Answer (score 2):

DNS is basically a database, mapping domain name to IP. What happens when a request is sent to that IP is independent of DNS.

Your section question "Is it possible to have a routeable IP without a server behind it, and if so, how do I shut it down?", isn't really clear. A request to an IP with no server will time out.

Comment: I realize that, and I guess I phrased it badly. I'm trying to figure out where the entry is that produces a name on nslookup, since the related IP's no longer appear in our inventory.

Comment: Your registrar points at a name server. The name server has the mapping between name and IP address. If you tell us the server name we can have a look for you.

Answer (score 1):

Because the DNS entry for this server is resolvable doesn't mean that the ip address it resolves to is "routable" or reachable. Do an nslookup for the SOA/NS records for the domain in question and find out who is authoritative for the domain. That's who is hosting the DNS record for this FQDN.

Additionally, I can host any number of DNS records that resolve to ip addresses that aren't in actually use. DNS doesn't validate that there's something, or anything at all, at the ip address that the record resolves to.